# How can I make my desktop app interact with my plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, uipath

I want to make a app like UiPath UI explorer. The app will interact with chrome extension(that i'll make), which will fetch the web element attributes from the website and send it to my desktop app. I am looking for a faster solution to pass those attributes to my desktop app. So, I would like to understand how UiPath does that or some other solution for the same.

Comment: Extensions have [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API.

Comment: A sample app is linked in the documentation. You can google up more samples if needed.

Comment: nativeMessaging is the only method. Other than that, you can listen on an http port in your app so the extension will periodically poll it.